# how to solve Runtime error 3704 in visual basic 6.0?

Tags: vb6

I am getting **Runtime 3704 Operation is not allowed when the object is closed** error Please help me to solve this error, my code is -

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Ado.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & (App.Path & "\Test.mdb") & ";Persist Security Info=False;")
    Ado.RecordSource = "select * from Emp"
    Ado.Refresh
Call RSRun("select EmpName from Emp")
lst.Clear
lst.AddItem ("All")
While RS.EOF = False
lst.AddItem (RS.Fields(0).Value)
RS.MoveNext
Wend
End Sub
```

Im modules

```
Public Sub RSRun(ByVal SqlStr As String)
   On Error GoTo Er
    Set RS = Nothing
RS.Open SqlStr, Conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

Exit Sub
Er:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "error-" & Err.Number
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Yugal

Comment: I assume `RS` is defined using `As New` because you are not instantiating it. Where is `Conn` defined and could it be closed at the point when `RS.Open...` is called? What type of object is your `Ado` variable? Why doesn't the `RS` object use the same connection object as your `Ado` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is `Conn` defined and could it be closed at the point when `RS.Open...` is called?